# Can't connect to local wordpress server

Tags: wordpress

I'm hosting a Wordpress server on a raspberry pi. After trying to port forward it, I broke my ability to connect to it locally. The local IP for the PI is 10.0.0.62, and putting that IP in the address bar redirects me to http://10.0.0.62/10.0.0.62/wp-admin/, preventing connection.

I've tried entering the MySQL tables and replacing the home and siteurl settings to 10.0.0.62; this doesn't help. Any thoughts?

Comment: May I see the output of the SQL query: select * from wp_options where option_name in ('home','siteurl');

Comment: Both home and siteurl are 10.0.0.62 according to that command.

Comment: Are those the exact values of option_value?

Comment: Yep, should I add http:// to them? Also, should I set one of them to my external IP address?

Comment: Yes, I think they should be URL's not hostnames or IP addresses.

Comment: Here is what I am using: http: //192.168.1.141 - I think I had a problem when I used only the ip address.

Comment: Sweet, that did the trick. Thanks!